# Compilation failure - Static Variable example

Tags: java, compiler-errors

While executing below program in JAVA, i'm getting error at line 14. Could you please help me why?

```
public class Triangle{

static double area;
int b=2, h=3;
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Static variable" +area);
        double p,b,h;
        if (area==0){
            b=3;
            h=4;
            p=0;
            System.out.println("sos");
        }
        area = p*b*h;
        //System.out.println("Area is "+ area);
     }
}
```

o/p compilation failure:

```
$javac Triangle.java
Triangle.java:14: error: variable p might not have been initialized
        area = p*b*h;
               ^
Triangle.java:14: error: variable b might not have been initialized
        area = p*b*h;
                 ^
Triangle.java:14: error: variable h might not have been initialized
        area = p*b*h;
                   ^
3 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Triangle{

static double area;
int b=2, h=3;
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Static variable" +area);
        double p,b,h;
        if (area==0){
            b=3;
            h=4;
            p=0;
            System.out.println("sos");
        }
        area = p*b*h;
        //System.out.println("Area is "+ area);
     }
}
```

In case you were wondering, the ints are being ignored.

```
double p,b,h;
```

these are the ones used. They only get initialized when `area == 0`
they have to be initialized for every scenario. Change the

```
double p,b,h;
```

line to:

```
double p=0,b=0,h=0;
```

Remember: local variables don't get default values.

EDIT: another option is to move the line:

```
area = p*b*h;
```

within the if-block.

Answer (score 0):

You have a branching statement with `if (area == 0)`; the fact that you can infer it must be zero does not imply the compiler can (and it *suggests* you made a mistake, because if that is your expectation why have an `if`). Thus the compiler is correct in telling you `p` might not be initialized. Change `double p,b,h;` to `double p = 0, b = 3, h = 4;` and remove the `if`. Or provide an `else` for when the `area` is not zero.